# Remove pageheader ad page footer from crystalreport

Tags: crystal-reports

i must print a report from my application like this :

```
section1(reportheader)
section2(pageheader)
section3(detailes)
     some data
....
...
....
section4(report footer)
section5(page footer)
```

in design area ,i set distance between section1 and section2 to zero,and between section2 and 3 and section 4 and 5 to zero too,but when i tried to print i got 2.2 cm gap from header and 2.2 cm gap from footer and my print messed, how do i remove this white spaces from my page?

Answer (score 1):

In Design view Right Click on the section you need and Select "Suppress". So the sections you suppressed will not be visible in your report. 

Try this and get back with your results.

Comment: i done this all,my sections of header and footer became gray, but nothing happened,for more information: my page size is h:42,30 V:55 and it has no margins. i checke off the noprinter .... and i chosed my printer model Epson LQ 2190 ESC/P2 my repoort is for a raw form that in every row it has five block that every bloak paced by some information ,my paper size is for five row of this blocks, still, now in my header's report i got 2.2 cm white space and after 4 row printing , i got 2.2 cm in footer and between row 4 and 5 i got 4.4 cm free space

Answer (score 0):

i done this all,my sections of header and footer became gray, but nothing happened,for more information: my page size is h:42,30 V:55 and it has no margins. i checke off the noprinter .... and i chosed my printer model Epson LQ 2190 ESC/P2 my repoort is for a raw form that in every row it has five block that every bloak paced by some information ,my paper size is for five row of this blocks, still, now in my header's report i got 2.2 cm white space and after 4 row printing , i got 2.2 cm in footer and between row 4 and 5 i got 4.4 cm free space